# How to reshape the res5c layer of ResNet (3D to 2D)?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, caffe, resnet

I extract the features of an image with ResNet of the `'res5c'` layer, resulting of a numpy array of shape `(2048, 14, 14)`

I have trouble manipulating these dimensions. I understand there is 14*14 features of size 2048. I would like to iterate over to access every feature at a time.

Therefore, how I can reshape this to an array of (14*14, 2048) without mistakes and then easily iterate over it with a for loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.  Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the features after `net.forward()`:

```
feat = net.blobs['res5c'].data.cop() # copy to be on the safe side.
```

As you describe, `feat` is an `np.array` with `shape = (2048, 14, 14)`.
You can [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it:

```
feat.reshape((2048,-1)) # fix the first dimension to 2048, -1 set the number of features to match that of `feat`.
```

Now you can iterate over features:

```
for fi in xrange(feat.shape[1]):
    f = feat[:,fi] # get the fi-th feature
    # do somethinf to the feature f
```

Comment: It works great. If i fully understand, would this work to get `(14, 14, 2048)` :

`x= x.reshape((2048,-1))` then 
`x = np.swapaxes(x,0,1)`
`x= x.reshape((14,14,2048))`

Comment: @Mickey look at [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html). But do you want to do that? what's wrong with `feat[:,fi]`? Are you trying to export data to Matlab?

Comment: I'm working with python but its silly, I just want to use a function that accept as input tensor of shapes (W,H, Feature). My low knowledge of reshaping is giving me trouble :-) I'll have a look to do this with transpose

Comment: @Mickey you have `feat` with shape `(F,H,W)` after `feat.transpose((2,1,0))` your shape is `(W,H,F)`.